# reverse animation at end with AnimationDrawable in Android

Tags: android, animation, drawable

How to reverse an AnimationDrawable in Android.

To optimize my app, i want to reverse my animation when it reachs the end.

Here is my code :

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball1), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball2), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball3), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball4), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball5), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball6), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball5), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball4), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball3), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball2), 100);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball1), 100);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    animation.start();
```

I wish the animation changes direction rather than loading 5 new images but i don't found how to do that.

thanks

Thibault

Answer (score -1):

add this interpolator

```
 public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
  @Override
  public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
    return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f);
  }
 }


 animation.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());
```

Comment: can't use method "setInterpolator()" on AnimationDrawable